# Calling function from within functions.php returns unwanted value

Tags: php, wordpress

When I call the comment count function below from within my functions.php file, I get "0" even though the post has comments. When I call the function from another page template (`<?php echo fb_comment_count(); ?>`), the correct comment number shows.

I have tried debugging to check the value of $post inside the fb_comment_count function and it generates the following:

`id = 818 id = 818 id = 818 id = 818 id = 818 id = 818 id = 818 id = 818`

This is wrong since each of those ids should be different for each of the attachment pages the image is on. 818 is the id of the entire gallery page itself. I suppose this is why I keep getting "0" for the comment count since the gallery page (id 818) itself has no comments.

To give a better idea of what I'm trying to do, here is a template for the gallery page. Each of those images are linked to their respective attachment pages. The white box with the number inside is the comment count.

[image: gallery]

If anybody can help me figure out how to retrieve the correct comment count for each of the images in the gallery, I'd be very grateful. Thank you.

Here is the fb_comment_count function.

```
// FB Comment Count (by Zack Austin)
function fb_comment_count($link = 'link') {
  global $post;
  $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/';
  $posturl = get_permalink($post->ID);
  $url .= $posturl;

  $filecontent = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($url, array('sslverify'=>false)));
  $json = json_decode($filecontent);
  $count = $json->comments;
  if ($count == 0 || !isset($count)) {
    $count = 0;
  }

  $comments = $count;
  if ($count == 1) {
    $comments .= '';
  }
  elseif ($count == 0) {
    $comments = '0';
  }
  elseif ($count > 1) {
    $comments .= '';
  }
  if ($link == 'nolink') {
    return $comments;
  }
  else {
    return '<a href="'.$posturl.'#comments" title="Comments for '.$post->post_title.'">'.$comments.'</a>';
  }
}
```

And here is the custom gallery code where I'm calling the fb_comment_count function above (about 22 lines from the bottom). Both the code below and the code above are in my functions.php file.

```
// Custom Gallery
add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'my_post_gallery', 10, 2 );
function my_post_gallery( $output, $attr) {
    global $post, $wp_locale;

    static $instance = 0;
    $instance++;

    // We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid orderby statement
    if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
        $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
        if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
            unset( $attr['orderby'] );
    }

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
        'id'         => $post->ID,
        'itemtag'    => 'dl',
        'icontag'    => 'dt',
        'captiontag' => 'dd',
        'columns'    => 3,
        'size'       => 'thumbnail',
        'include'    => '',
        'exclude'    => ''
    ), $attr));

    $id = intval($id);
    if ( 'RAND' == $order )
        $orderby = 'none';

    if ( !empty($include) ) {
        $include = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include );
        $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

        $attachments = array();
        foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
            $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
        }
    } elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
        $exclude = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $exclude );
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    } else {
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    }

    if ( empty($attachments) )
        return '';

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        $output = "\n";
        foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
            $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
        return $output;
    }

    $itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
    $captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
    $columns = intval($columns);
    $itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
    $float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

    $selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

    $output = apply_filters('gallery_style', "
        <style type='text/css'>
            #{$selector} {
                margin: auto;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-item {
                float: {$float};
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                width: {$itemwidth}%;           }
            #{$selector} img {
                border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php -->
        <div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id}'>");

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
        $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);

        $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
        $output .= "<span class='photos-comment-number-wrap'><span class='comment-number'>". fb_comment_count() ."</span></span>";
        $output .= "
            <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon'>
                $link
            </{$icontag}>";
        if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
            $output .= "
                <{$captiontag} class='gallery-caption'>
                " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
                </{$captiontag}>";
        }
        $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
        if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
            $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
    }

    $output .= "
            <br style='clear: both;' />
        </div>\n";

    return $output;
}
```

Update:

```
// FB Comment Count (by Zack Austin)
function fb_comment_count($link = 'link', $post) {
  $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/';
  $posturl = get_permalink($post->ID);
  $url .= $posturl;

  $filecontent = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($url, array('sslverify'=>false)));
  $json = json_decode($filecontent);
  $count = $json->comments;
  if ($count == 0 || !isset($count)) {
    $count = 0;
  }

  $comments = $count;
  if ($count == 1) {
    $comments .= '';
  }
  elseif ($count == 0) {
    $comments = '0';
  }
  elseif ($count > 1) {
    $comments .= '';
  }
  if ($link == 'nolink') {
    return $comments;
  }
  else {
    return '<a href="'.$posturl.'#comments" title="Comments for '.$post->post_title.'">'.$comments.'</a>';
  }
}

// Custom Gallery
add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'my_post_gallery', 10, 2 );
function my_post_gallery( $output, $attr) {
    global $post, $wp_locale;

    static $instance = 0;
    $instance++;

    // We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid orderby statement
    if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
        $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
        if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
            unset( $attr['orderby'] );
    }

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
        'id'         => $post->ID,
        'itemtag'    => 'dl',
        'icontag'    => 'dt',
        'captiontag' => 'dd',
        'columns'    => 3,
        'size'       => 'thumbnail',
        'include'    => '',
        'exclude'    => ''
    ), $attr));

    $id = intval($id);
    if ( 'RAND' == $order )
        $orderby = 'none';

    if ( !empty($include) ) {
        $include = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include );
        $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

        $attachments = array();
        foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
            $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
        }
    } elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
        $exclude = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $exclude );
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    } else {
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    }

    if ( empty($attachments) )
        return '';

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        $output = "\n";
        foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
            $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
        return $output;
    }

    $itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
    $captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
    $columns = intval($columns);
    $itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
    $float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

    $selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

    $output = apply_filters('gallery_style', "
        <style type='text/css'>
            #{$selector} {
                margin: auto;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-item {
                float: {$float};
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                width: {$itemwidth}%;           }
            #{$selector} img {
                border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php -->
        <div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id}'>");

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment ) {
        $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);

        $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
        $output .= "<span class='photos-comment-number-wrap'><span class='comment-number'>". fb_comment_count('link', $attachment) ."</span></span>";
        $output .= "
            <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon'>
                $link
            </{$icontag}>";
        $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
        if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
            $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
    }

    $output .= "
            <br style='clear: both;' />
        </div>\n";

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the function fb_comment_count call a optional variable, here I will call it $id, which will contains the ID of the attachement (optional so it will not break the function in other areas of site). Then with that ID we can get the attachment page's URL with get_attachment_link, is in that page that we'll find the comments for attachment. The code should be something like:

```
<?php
// FB Comment Count (by Zack Austin)
// Changes by Bruno Cantuaria (bruno@cantuaria.net.br)
function fb_comment_count($link = 'link', $id = 0) {
    global $post;

    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/';
    if ($id > 0)
        $posturl = get_attachment_link($id);
    else
        $posturl = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $url .= $posturl;

    $filecontent = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($url, array('sslverify'=>false)));
    $json = json_decode($filecontent);
    $count = $json->comments;
    if ($count == 0 || !isset($count)) {
    $count = 0;
    }

    $comments = $count;
    if ($count == 1) {
    $comments .= '';
    }
    elseif ($count == 0) {
    $comments = '0';
    }
    elseif ($count > 1) {
    $comments .= '';
    }
    if ($link == 'nolink') {
    return $comments;
    }
    else {
    return '<a href="'.$posturl.'#comments" title="Comments for '.$post->post_title.'">'.$comments.'</a>';
    }
}

// Custom Gallery
add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'my_post_gallery', 10, 2 );
function my_post_gallery( $output, $attr) {
    global $post, $wp_locale;

    static $instance = 0;
    $instance++;

    // We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid orderby statement
    if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
        $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
        if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
            unset( $attr['orderby'] );
    }

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
        'id'         => $post->ID,
        'itemtag'    => 'dl',
        'icontag'    => 'dt',
        'captiontag' => 'dd',
        'columns'    => 3,
        'size'       => 'thumbnail',
        'include'    => '',
        'exclude'    => ''
    ), $attr));

    $id = intval($id);
    if ( 'RAND' == $order )
        $orderby = 'none';

    if ( !empty($include) ) {
        $include = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include );
        $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

        $attachments = array();
        foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
            $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
        }
    } elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
        $exclude = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $exclude );
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    } else {
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    }

    if ( empty($attachments) )
        return '';

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        $output = "\n";
        foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
            $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
        return $output;
    }

    $itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
    $captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
    $columns = intval($columns);
    $itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
    $float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

    $selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

    $output = apply_filters('gallery_style', "
        <style type='text/css'>
            #{$selector} {
                margin: auto;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-item {
                float: {$float};
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                width: {$itemwidth}%;           }
            #{$selector} img {
                border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php -->
        <div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id}'>");

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($attachments as $id => $attachment) {
        $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);

        $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
        $output .= "<span class='photos-comment-number-wrap'><span class='comment-number'>". fb_comment_count('link', $id) ."</span></span>";
        $output .= "
            <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon'>
                $link
            </{$icontag}>";
        $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
        if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
            $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
    }

    $output .= "
            <br style='clear: both;' />
        </div>\n";

    return $output;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should call `function fb_comment_count($link = 'link') {` and pass in the atachemnt post object so it would look like `function fb_comment_count($link = 'link', $post) {`, and **remove** the `global $post` just after.

this should be called from within the foreach loop that generates the gallery, just here:

```
 foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
       fb_comment_count('link', $attachment);
```

also, you should really post wordpress question over at wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for helping! I changed the code to reflect your reply, however, I get a "missing attachment" error. Furthermore, on other parts of the site where I call the function from within a template (`<?php echo fb_comment_count(); ?>`), I get a "Missing argument 2 for fb_comment_count()" error. Got any ideas? I updated the new code by the way in the original post. Also, I'll make sure to keep my WordPress questions only on that site from now.